# Undefined reference warning

Tags: cross-referencing

Edit: The problem was pointed out to me. After compiling I cleared the aux-file automatically. That can't prevents LaTeX from doing the cross-referencing right.

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works for me.
I use references in my code but I always get the following warning:

Reference `ref:table2' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.

The PDF works correctly and everything, but with a larger document it's a little hard not to get overwhelmed.
So, how can I get rid of this warning?
I already compiled multiple times.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\label{ref:table2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}
\hline
Text & Text \\
\hline
Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Reference to table~\ref{ref:table2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You will get the warning on the first run, it goes on the second, (the PDF will _not_ be correct when you get the warning, it will print ?? instead of a number)

Comment: unrelated but `\begin{table}[htb]` does not include `p` so makes it quite likely that tables go to the end of the document.

Comment: are you cleaning up files between the compilations? If you delete the aux-file the warning will not disappear.

Comment: Yeah, I cleared the aux-file in between. That makes sense. Thank you very much!